# Sum of infinite series by hand

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering how to generate the sum of infinite series for something simple like $$\sum_{x=1}^\infty 5^{-x}$$
I can't seem to figure out the logic as to why it comes out as 1/4 and I was unable to find a breakdown of the process that I would be capable of applying on the other simple similar problems.

Comment: It's a geometric series. You can find formulas here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$S:=\frac15+\frac1{25}+\frac1{125}+\frac1{625}+\cdots$$
then

$$5S=1+\frac15+\frac1{25}+\frac1{125}+\cdots.$$

Make a second link with $S$ and conclude.

---

You can also work it out "experimentally", computing the successive terms by hand (this is not very difficult)

$$0.2\\+0.04=0.24\\+0.008=0.248\\+0.0016=0.2496\\+0.00032=0.24992\\+0.000064=0.249984\\+0.0000128=0.2499968\\\cdots$$

Then you can conjecture that the limit is $\dfrac14$.

To prove it more formally, compute the differences

$$\frac14-\frac15=\frac1{20},\\
\frac14-\frac15-\frac1{25}=\frac1{100},\\
\frac14-\frac15-\frac1{25}-\frac1{125}=\frac1{500},\\\cdots
$$

You quickly observe the pattern, $\dfrac1{4\cdot5^n}$ and conclude that the partial sums are

$$\frac14-\frac1{4\cdot5^n}.$$

Then by induction

$$\left(\frac14-\frac1{4\cdot 5^n}\right)-\frac1{5^{n+1}}=\frac14-\frac1{4\cdot 5^{n+1}}.$$